# npm reports an error when installing hexo

Tags: javascript, npm, hexo

Use npm to install hexo and execute this command `npm install hexo-deployer-git --save`. The error message is: npm ERR! Cannot read properties of null (reading 'matches'),

[image]

I tried clearing the cache: `npm cache clean --force`, but it still didn't work

Comment: Try to clear npm cache: `npm cache clean --force` and then try to install again. also you can try to reinstall hexo globally `npm uninstall hexo -g` then `npm install -g hexo`